# how to apply a regex to a bamboo variable

Tags: bamboo

I have a bamboo plan with Maven task:

```
verify -B -Dsonar.branch=${bamboo.repository.branch.name}
```

the problem is that we have a git branch name that contains a '/': "feature/CATALOG", and this is not a valid sonar.branch name.
If I would be running a script task instead of a Maven task, I would replace / by _ as follows:

```
mvn verify -B -Dsonar.branch=$(echo ${bamboo.repository.branch.name} | tr / _
```

Is there a way to achieve this with a Maven task?
that is, is it possible to change a variable with a regex or something else?

ps: I am aware that bamboo is a bad choice, and we are eventually moving to jenkins. however we still need to use bamboo for a while.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue yourself? I have the same issue, I'm running in Windows environment and tried to solve this by running a powershell script before which created an enviroment variable, but concluded that the bamboo maven process only looked for ${system.XXXXX} system variables in the process scope, so no luck for me. I'm not sure how this would work if you're running on some *nix machine.

Comment: we didn't find out. we moved to jenkins.