# Bamboo plan with a variable which depends on another variable, it works in some circumstances

Tags: bamboo

I have a bamboo plan with a maven task. I need to pass a maven parameter with the name of the branch.
I can use the variable `${bamboo.repository.branch.name}` for this.

However, I need to override this value for some branches (see [how to apply a regex to a bamboo variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072272/how-to-apply-a-regex-to-a-bamboo-variable) ).

So, in my bamboo plan I define a variable called `branchName`, with value `${bamboo.repository.branch.name}`.
then, my maven task uses `${bamboo.branchName}`, and the branches can override the `branchName` value when necessary.

So, is this possible? can my bamboo plan variable `branchName` use another variable `${bamboo.repository.branch.name}` as default value?

Well, I tried, and the result is unclear.
If my maven task is:

```
  mvn verify -B -Dsonar.branch=${bamboo.branchName}
```

this does not work. it executes `mvn verify -B -Dsonar.branch=${bamboo.repository.branch.name}`

However, 
If my maven task is:

```
  mvn verify -B -Dsonar.branch=${bamboo.branchName}  -Dignore_var=${bamboo.repository.branch.name}
```

then `${bamboo.branchName}` gets substituted as expected,
and it executes `mvn verify -B -Dsonar.branch=develop -Dignore_var=develop`

Why is that? Is this a bug or a feature?

So, how to achieve this correctly?
that is, I need a bamboo plan variable `branchName` with a default value of `${bamboo.repository.branch.name}`,
which can be overridden by branch plans.

ps: I am aware that bamboo is a bad choice, and we are eventually moving to jenkins. however we still need to use bamboo for a while.

Comment: Might be better to ask this on the [Atlassian Site](https://answers.atlassian.com/)